# Montar um array bidimensional a partir de outro array

Tags: php, array-multidimensional

Tenho o array `$dados` abaixo:

```
array(5) {
   [0]=> "2018-03-28"
   [1]=> "jantar"
   [2]=> "lanche"
   [3]=> "2018-03-29"
   [4]=> "lanche"
}
```

A partir desse array, como eu poderia montar outro array bidimensional para que fique desta forma:

```
$dados1 = array(
   '2018-03-28' => array('jantar','lanche'),
   '2018-03-29' => array('lanche')
);
```

Observe que a cada item em forma de *data* deve-se criar um novo array dentro de `$dados1` e essa array conter os itens subsequentes até a próxima *data*.

Como não sei montar esse tipo de array com PHP, não consegui pensar numa forma de fazer isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível sim fazer isso que você quer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
// Seu array inicial
$array = array("2018-03-28", "jantar", "lanche","2018-03-29", "lanche");

// Declaração do array final e variável auxiliar de data
$dados1 = array();
$data_atual = null;

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // Verifica se o $value é uma data
    if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value)) == $value) {
        // Salva qual a data atual para o array bidimensional
        $data_atual = $value;
    }else{
        // Adiciona o tipo de refeição na data atual
        $dados1[$data_atual][] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($dados1);
?>
```

O var_dump sairá uma resposta do tipo:

> array(2) { ["2018-03-28"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "jantar" [1]=> string(6) "lanche" } ["2018-03-29"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "lanche" } }

**Edit para casos de data no formato "2018-03-1":**

```
<?php 
$array = array("2018-03-1", "jantar", "lanche","2018-03-29", "lanche");

$dados1 = array();
$data_atual = null;

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $data1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value));
    $data2 = $value;

    // Verifica se o $value é uma data
    if (strtotime($data1) == strtotime($data2)) {
        $data_atual = $value;
    }else{
        $dados1[$data_atual][] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($dados1);
?>
```

O `var_dump` sairá uma resposta do tipo:

> array(2) { ["2018-03-1"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "jantar" [1]=> string(6) "lanche" } ["2018-03-29"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "lanche" } }

Comment: Estranho, nesse site o exit realmente finalizou antes do var_dump. No meu localhost não ocorreu esse problema. Vou apagar do meu exemplo :)

Comment: Funcionou certinho. Obg!

Comment: @dvd na real nem o `var_dump` é necessário hehe. Foi só um exemplo pra mostrar a saída do array.

Comment: Xará, deixa eu tirar uma dúvida: quando a data é tipo 2018-03-1 (o dia com apenas 1 dígito) não funciona... Alguma dica de como poderia contornar isso?

Comment: O resultado fica assim: `array(2) { [""]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(9) "2018-03-1" [1]=> string(6) "Jantar" [2]=> string(6) "Lanche" } ["2018-03-29"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Lanche" } }`

Comment: Veja que o primeiro item fica vazio

Comment: Se for mt complicado eu coloco no banco com 2 digitos mesmo, igual ao mês

Comment: @dvd fiz uma edição na resposta que resolve seu problema

Comment: Valeu cara Obg!